# tar returns error but still unpacks file even though "tar --no-ignore-command-error -xvzf file.tar.gz" is used

Tags: tar, error-handling

I have a corrupted file called file.tar.gz and I want to the extraction of it to fail. I used `tar --no-ignore-command-error -xvzf file.tar.gz` but it still extracting the files, and ignoring the errors:

```
[root@SmartSwitch zconf]# tar --no-ignore-command-error -xvzf a.tar.gz
gzip: crc error
gzip: error inflating
DBversion
License
textual_db.txt
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 3):

When you extract a compressed archive, GNU `tar` runs `gzip -d` to decompress the data.  If the archive is corrupt in such a way that `gzip` can't decompress it properly, you will get `gzip` errors like the ones you report in the question.

`tar` will read the data that `gzip` successfully decompresses and exit when that data has been processed (with an error if the end of the uncompressed archive occurs unexpectedly, as you show).

The `--no-ignore-command-error` option (which is set by default) is primarily useful together with the `--to-command=utility` option, and [according to the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html), especially if you have `--ignore-command-error` as part of the `TAR_OPTIONS` environment variable.

It is unclear whether `--no-ignore-command-error` and `--ignore-command-error` has any effect on child processes *not* started through `--to-command=utility`.